# Set scroll with object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i've searched google, this website and still cannot find out how to set the scroll postion on an object(iframe) This is my jquery Code

```
function runeServer(){
object = $('.vote_content_webpage').html('<object id="webpage" type="text/html"       data="http://www.runelocus.com/toplist/index.php?action=vote&&id=20923&data=<?php echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; ?>" width="100%" height="95%"/>');
$('#webpage').scrollTo(500);
}
```

Comment: The html function in jQuery actually sets the HTML content of the referenced element, here `.vote_content_webpage`. If you want to set the width and height of your element you should use `$('.vote_content_webpage').attr('width', '100%').attr('height', '95%');`. It probably won't solve your problem, but it might help your development.

Comment: You still need help on this?

Comment: Also The object is what i need to scroll, not the div, i want it to load the page in a div then Scroll to selected postion